# How to test actor which not send anything to sender

Tags: unit-testing, akka.net

I have following message flow
ConnectionActor -(RawMessage)-> ParserActor -(ParsedMessage)-> ProcessingActor -(DataMessage)-> DataStoreActor.

I want to test that my ProcessingActor sends proper DataMessage when ParserActor received some particular RawMessage. Is it possible to do it using Akka.TestKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going further, I'd encourage you to take a look at [Akka.Streams](http://getakka.net/docs/streams/quickstart) to evaluate, if your stream processing couldn't be made easier and faster with that.

Given that, you could simply express a link between two actors in your flow as i.e. `IActorRef` passed to actor's constructor like `public ParserActor(IActorRef processingActor)`. This way you can keep components of your flow separate and mock the connection between them using standard test probe or actor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at the Akka.Streams.

Actually, I'm using DI, so it's not so easy to put actor ref to constructor. I decided to set DataStoreActor ref for ProcessingActor by sending Configure message with DataStoreActor reference.